# Twill и proxy

Tags: python, proxy

Подскажите, как использовать twill с socks-прокси (tor) в Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я просто попробовал поискать и нашел [этот форк](https://bitbucket.org/yokotoka/twill) (который и был специально создан для поддержки twill'ом socks-прокси).

Как альтернативу попробуйте [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (можно даже безголовый вариант). Так как он не эмулирует браузер, а работает в нем, вам (по идее) будут доступны все функции браузера, в том числе работа через `socks`, поддержка JS.